# Remove duplication in layout xml files

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, duplicates

I have two layouts (~80 lines) which differ from each other only in several text values. Can I remove such a duplication via xml? Or I can do it only programmatically by setting different string resources each time?

Simple example:

first xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_top"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_bottom"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <View
        android:layout_height="@dimen/space_between_image_and_text"
        android:layout_width="1dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/title_1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_title"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/details_1"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

second xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_top"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_bottom"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <View
        android:layout_height="@dimen/space_between_image_and_text"
        android:layout_width="1dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/title_2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_title"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/details_2"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

They differ only by text values: `@string/title_1` vs `@string/title_2`, and, `@string/details_1` vs `@string/details_2`.

*Sorry for my English*

Comment: can you elaborate your question please

Comment: ' can do it programmatically' will be the better option I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use the same layout - give the textviews id's and set the strings after inflation